# Maximum weight matching in bipartite graphs with constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph, bipartite

Assume that we have two sets: A=(a_1,a_2,...,a_m) and B=(b_1,b_2,...,a_n) (Not necessarily of same size). A function F assigns a weight to each link from set A to set B: F:A*B->R. So, for example, F(a_1,b_1)=2 means that the weight of the link between a_1 and b_1 is 2.
The problem is to connect the elements of set A to those of set B in order to maximize the sum of the link weights satisfying these constraints:

- The elements of set A must be matched to exactly one element of set B.
- Elements of set B are allowed to have zero or more matching (0,1,2...) although a constraint on the sum of weights C_i exists for the elements of B. That is, if we choose to connect a_1 to b_1, and a_2 to b_1, the sum of weights F(a_1,b_1)+F(a_2,b_1) should be less than or equal to C_1. This constraint is there for all elements of B.

I have searched for some ideas and I looked into the assignment problems and the Hungarian algorithm. The additional thing is that none of these consider the second constraint I have. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's NP-hard.

Take a subset-sum instance {x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>}, where x<sub>i</sub> > 0 and a number k. Create a bipartite graph where left vertices are {a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>}, right vertices are {b<sub>1</sub>,b<sub>2</sub>}, and:

F(a<sub>i</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>) = x<sub>i</sub>

F(a<sub>i</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>) = 0

C<sub>1</sub> = k

C<sub>2</sub> = 0

So you can take the number x<sub>i</sub> by connecting a<sub>i</sub> with b<sub>1</sub>, and leave it by connecting with b<sub>2</sub>. Obviously there is a weight k matching iff the subset sum instance has a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I didn't actually get what you meant. I am already given the function F and the constraints C_1 to C_n for each element in B, I want to select the optimal edges that connect these two sets according to the given constraints. Maybe you can please elaborate more on your idea.

Comment: Are you familiar with NP-completeness? There is no known polynomial time algorithm for the subset sum problem. I reduced subset sum to your question. Therefore, if there was a fast algorithm for your question, there would be one for subset sum (and P=NP).  This is a [major unsolved problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%3DNP). In short: it is open whether a fast algorithm for your problem exists, but probably it does not.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with NP-completeness. But my problem is that I don't require the sum to be exact (I have inequality rather than equality with constraints C_i), and the function F maps to R not integers, does this still qualify as a subset sum problem?

Comment: Yes. In detail: it is NP-complete to tell given x_i if there is a subset summing exactly to k. But if there was a fast algorithm A to your problem, you could solve subset sum. Given an instance of subset sum, create the graph, use the algorithm A, find the maximum weight matching not exceeding the constraints, and answer "yes" iff the maximum matching found by the algorithm has weight exactly k. If the algorithm will find a smaller matching, then since it is maximum weight, there is no matching of weight k. Mapping to R instead of integers does not make the problem easier.

Comment: @user1454747 sdcvvc is correct in all points. You might still come up with a good heuristic. Also if you relax any of the two conditions, a good algorithm comes in handy: if you relax 1, you could use maxflow by making the graph tripartite with b_i->c_i width function as C_i and a_i->c_i=0. If you relax 2, you can use mincost-maxflow.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but is there any better idea than the brute force approach?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything better than backtracking. There might be some way to decrease the exponent by half, as in subset sum, but I do not see it here. Maybe someone else will.

Comment: Thanks again. I have two questions though. 1- I forget to mention the fact that F maps to [0,1] not to the real numbers. Does the fact that it is positive and bounded between 0 and 1 helps? 2- If it doesn't, I can think of relaxing constraint 2 to the following: Elements of set B are allowed to have zero and up to k matching (0,1,2,...,k). Can we find an algorithm to solve this?

Comment: (1) does not help: you can always enforce it by adding a constant to all edges, and scaling by sum; this brings codomain of F to [0,1]. As for (2), if you remove the "total weight<=C_i" constraint, you can replace all vertices in B by k copies of vertices in B, and find a maximum weight matching (by Hungarian algorithm, for example).

Comment: @sdcvvc Thanks this was so helpful.

Comment: I just found a solution for my issue. The problem can be seen as a [Generalized Assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem) and it can be then formulated as a binary integer program. It is indeed NP-complete.